# PHP round() bug with round(908.5449, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) = 908.54?

Tags: php

I am currently investing a rounding problem in PHP.
I've tested it here https://3v4l.org/NpRPp and it seems to be the same, since ever.

But is this correct behaviour? Because i expected the following.

```
echo round(908.5449, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); // should be 908.55, but returns actually 908.54
```

Can someone tell if this behaviour is intended, and if so, how to solve it properly for every possible floating point number?

Edit: Thanks to the answers, this behaviour is correct but i expected the wrong result. My original number in the program was `908.55` which somewhere in the chain of the program became `908.5449999999994` due to storage in DB and floating point precision issues. So i wanted it to be `908.55` again, which does not work with regular use of `round()`.

Comment: I would have thought that the 49 on the end would be rounded down as it's less than half.

Comment: Can you explain **why** you expect anything else?

Comment: @NicoHaase I assumed a wrong result due to a floating point precision problem which caused the original number "908.55" became "908.5449999999994" and i wanted it to be 908.55 again... Wrong thoughts from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working correctly. The output of

```
echo round(908.5449, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Should be `908.54`. You're rounding to two decimals, so the remainder, that is rounded off is 0.0049. This is less than 0.005, which would be half, so it is rounded down.

Comment: Awesome, i never thought that  way. That answered my question, as it is how rounding works and i assumed wrong.